# Создание приложения для Android.

Tags: c#, android, java

В универе дали проектную тему: создание приложения под Android. Обычный парсер новостей. Но не суть. Дело вот в чем. Понимаю что приложения пишутся на Java в Eclipse или в любой другой IDE. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли SDK, в которых поддерживается возможность использования других яп для создания приложения ? С# ?
Видел на питоне реализацию. Но с C# увидел лишь один пример и тот был слишком мутный чтобы в нем можно было бы что нибудь увидеть. Или зная C# проще будет выучить Java и не парится... ?

Comment: да зачем вам эти шарп/пайтон или еще что-то? По java для android полно отличной документации, примеров, многие проблемные места миллион раз пережеваны (даже тут). И тем более с шарпа в принципе не так сложно перейти на java. Или у вас просто интерес именно написать на другом языке? Если нет, пишите на java

Comment: а лучше скачать пример готового парсера, сдать и забить

Comment: @Gorets, На счет готового вы правы, я так в принципе и собирался. @rasmisha, Просто мне самому интересно как работает программа (может что свое добавить, улучшить) и привязка к желаемому языку тут не особо важна, хотел лишь узнать, есть ли возможность использования других яп.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где-то полгода назад была новость о появлении возможности писать под Android на C#. Всё это замечательное мероприятие по портированию было затеяно компанией Xamarin (это те ребята, кто денно и нощно трудятся над Mono, пытаясь сделать, чтобы .NET был кроссплатформенным чуть более, чем никак)
А, впрочем, что я тут рассказываю. Лучше вот почитайте и сами все увидите: http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/05/01/android-in-c-sharp/

Надеюсь, этот проект жив, хотя не уверен

Comment: Жив. И продолжает развиватся. Правда стоит подобное удовольствие не так уж и дешево. От $250 до $1500. Есть еще триалка, нужно будет вечером поизучать.

Answer (score 3):

Я пишу программы под андроид на C++, добавляя графический интерфейс на java. Программы собранные на с++ под линукс без проблем компилируются под андроид. Сейчас занимаюсь парсером xml.

Answer (score 2):

Есть прекрасный инструмент от Адобе - Flash Builder + Air SDK

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-8000.html

ЯП Action Script 3 очень похож на C# и Java. Большой плюс в том что приложение можно собрать сразу для нескольких платформ (iOS/Android/Blackberry).

Comment: Спасибо. Вечером погляжу на SDK.

Comment: Что на него смотреть, ставьте Flash Builder 4.6 (4.7) и собирайте приложение, оно там создается в пару кликов + визуальный редактор UI.
У билдера триал на 2 месяца, а для учащихся он вообще бесплатен.

Comment: Да сейчас времени нет. В универ ухожу...

Answer (score 0):

достаточно понимать ЯП. Если так, не суть на чем писать. Пиша на Жава. ЯП отличаются, но не кардинально( на твоем уровне программы )

Comment: Ну, знаете, я вот понимаю языки программирования, но на джаве как-то не особо стараюсь писать. Делаю основной код на с++.